# How do I merge multiple columns with similar names in a Pandas Dataframe without losing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am working with some messy data and I'm trying to figure out how to merge multiple columns with similar information onto one column. For example I have a dataframe that looks like this and i want to know how to condense all three columns into one:

Country ------------State  ------  Temp ------ Temperature ------ Degrees

United States -----Kentucky --- $76  ------   76    --------------------    N/A

United States -----Arizona ----- 92\n   -------   N/A       ------------------         N/A

United States   -----   Michigan     --    45     -----------           45@    -----------------  60

Comment: In cases where Degrees and Temp and Temperature have valid differing values, what is your goal? Do you want to prioritize one over another?

Comment: This is just a a rough example as my real problem has to deal with sensitive data. However my goal would be to keep the two temperatures but have them separated with a "/" within the same column/row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, then drop the unwanted columns:

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: list([x['Temp'],
                                        x['Temperature'],
                                        x['Degrees']]),axis=1)
```

You can also do something like this if you want them separated with a slash

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.Temp + ' / ' + x.Temperature + ' / ' + x.Degrees, axis=1)

# or simply

df['combined'] = df.Temp + ' / ' + df.Temperature + ' / ' + df.Degrees
```

I tested this on some data i have with NaN data and it worked with NaN's, maybe worth a try:

```
import numpy as np
def combine_with_nan(x):
   try:
      np.isnan(x.Temp)
      Temp = 'NaN'
   except:
      Temp = x.Temp
   try:
      np.isnan(x.Temperature)
      Temperature = 'NaN'
   except:
      Temperature = x.Temperature
   try:
      np.isnan(x.Degrees)
      Degrees = 'NaN'
   except:
      Degrees = x.Degrees
   return Temp + ' / ' + Temperature + ' / ' + Degrees

df.apply(combine_with_nan, axis=1)
```

Comment: Doing `df.Temp + ' / ' + df.Temperature + ' / ' + df.Degrees` without `apply()` should be faster (and less code)

Comment: Just tried it, however it doesn't really merge the data into one column, rather it seems to create a list within each cell of the new column

Comment: Would this method work with NaN values while also keeping each temp in the same row?

Comment: No, unfortunately, with this one, you would have to do something like df.fillna('N/A') first. It would fail on nan data

Comment: Yeah thats my problem, I have about 15 columns with similar data thats spread out. So im trying to merge them onto one column while also keeping them within the same index as the data is linked to the clients information

Comment: @CodeMonkey I updated with something that worked on some data i have with nan's, maybe it will work for you? LMK

Comment: I think my problem is a little more complicated than i originally thought. I have about 3000 rows of names of clients, and about 400 columns of information relating to those clients. However almost all of the columns have a majority of missing data and it is spread out among 15 of the 400 columns with the empty spaces being NaN. I want to merge those 15 columns, some of which may contain duplicate values on to one column. The column has to be linked to the name. I tried my best to explain it, but im still not sure if that fully explains my issue. Thanks for your help so far, much appreciated .